# Folland real analysis problem $1.29a$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

I feel this proof is wrong since it's shorter than what I found online.

Define equivalence relation $\sim$ on $[0,1)$ such that the $x - y$ is rational.

Let $N$ contain exactly one element from each equivalence class.

Let $E$ be a lebesgue measurable subset of $N$.

Show $E$ has measure $0$.

Proof:

Take $[0,1/n)$ then this contains an element from each equivalence class. 
Let his be $N$, since $E$ is contained in it, $M(E)$ is less than epsilon , hence $0$.

PS: Is the fault that this $N$ is only a specific example? Can I use translation to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: $N$ is presented here to you as a **fixed** set. Construction of it ("Let this be $N$") is out of the question.

Comment: What you show is that for every $n$ there exist a set of representatives such that its measure is at most $\frac{1}{n}$. How does this imply that $E$ has measure $0$?

Answer (score 0):

> Exercise 29 - Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set
>
> a.) If $E\subset N$ where $N$ is a nonmeasurable set described in section 1.1, then $m(E) = 0$

Proof - Let $E\subset N$ and $N\subset [0,1)$. In the notation of section 1.1, let $$E_r = \{x + r: x\in E\cap [0,1-r)\}\cup\{ x + r - 1: x\in E\cap[1-r,1)\}$$
Then for all $r\in R = \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1)$, since $E_r\subset N_r$ and the collection $\{N_r\}_{r\in R}$ is a disjoint collection, it follows that $\{E_r\}_{r\in R}$ is a disjoint collection. By the translation invariance and finite additivity of Lebesgue measure, we have that each $E_r$ is measurable and $m(E_r) = m(E)$ for all $r\in R$. So,
$$1 \geq m\left(\bigcup_{r\in R}E_r\right) = \sum_{r\in R} m(E_r) = \sum_{r\in R} m(E)$$
and therefore $m(E) = 0$.

Comment: It seems like the asker was looking for flaws in their proof.  They already found a correct answer elsewhere apparently.

Comment: Ahh I see didn't read it completely just thought oh I know that and decided to post an answer anyways. Should I remove it?

Comment: How do we know that $E$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set?  It is possible to partition $[0,1]$ into  a countably infinite family of non-measurable sets, each with outer measure $1$.

Comment: It is stated in the question we assume $E$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set. As for your second comment that seems like that would work as well.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but if some of you receive this notification, could you justify why the  last sum `\sum_{r\in R} m(E) implies that m(E)=0? I could understand all the steps, but the last one... Maybe I'm missing some theore on my reading though.

Comment: @JakePark You are adding the same number to itself infinitely many times (namely, the number $m(E)$). The only way an infinite sum of of the same constant can be less than 1 is if that constant is 0. So the constant $m(E)$ has to be 0.